# Использование индексов в MySQL для увеличения скорости выполнения запросов

Tags: mysql

Нужно ли при запросе к базе указывать, что нужно как-то использовать индексы при запросе, или всё происходит автоматически?

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/MySQL_indexes.html + http://habrahabr.ru/post/70640/

Comment: Я уже несколько раз прочитал информацию по этим ссылкам, пока мало что понял :-(

Comment: Вот [рекомендую к прочтению](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%B2+MySQL) просто и понятно, даже чем на Хабре.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оптимизатор MySQL сам решает, какие индексы из имеющихся использовать при выполнении запроса. Узнать, что он там решил в каждом конкретном случае, можно, выполнив вместо запроса `SELECT что-то-там` запрос `EXPLAIN SELECT что-то-там`. EXPLAIN покажет, в числе прочего:

- Список индексов (один, или несколько, или NULL, если подходящих индексов нет), которые MySQL **может** использовать для выполнения данного запроса
- Индексы, которые **были** использованы для выполнения данного запроса
- Количество строк в таблице, которые пришлось перелопатить, чтобы выполнить запрос

Подробную информацию об `EXPLAIN` можно найти в [официальной документации MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html).

Answer (score 2):

Ну если индексы уже созданы, то они используются автоматически.
Чтобы более точно понимать, какие именно индексы используются (и используются ли они вообще) я бы рекомендовал проверить план выполнения через `EXPLAIN`, например

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM servers where ID = 100500
```

Вместо `select * ...` Вы должны написать свой запрос, который необходимо проверить. И далее обратить главное внимание на столбец key, в нем как раз отображаются используемые индексы для каждой из таблиц Вашего запроса.

Подробнее об планах выполнения написано уже много статей. Например, можно посмотреть эту http://habrahabr.ru/post/211022 .

Comment: Это уже более понятно. Спасибо.